# How to customize antdesign form scrollToFirstError behavior?

Tags: reactjs, antd

According to [documentation](https://4x.ant.design/components/form/#Form) scrollToFirstError behavior can be customized by passing function to it.

```
export interface CustomScrollAction {
    el: Element;
    top: number;
    left: number;
}
export declare type CustomScrollBehaviorCallback<T> = (actions: CustomScrollAction[]) => T;
```

However, I did not understand what exactly this function should do in order to change the behavior.

On my site, if there is an error in the first field on the form, after the page scrolls, this field is not visible, because the header overlaps it. I want to change the top coordinate to scroll to. Here is [jsfiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snow-qutbi4?file=/src/App.js) and a gif
How can this behavior be customized?

[image]

Comment: You can check the api for `scroll-into-view-if-needed`. Antd is using this package for scrollToFirstError behavior. [Scroll Into View If Needed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed)

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved without modifying `behavior` function

```
scrollToFirstError={{
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'center',
  inline: 'center',
}}
```